# MSAL, is recommended to go for the new version 2.0.0 preview

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm working on a solution that is using the library [MSAL](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) v.1.1.4 to be able to use the Graph API, I'm using the Confidential Client with the Authorization Code flow with a customised Token Cache to save it in a DB, it's working pretty good.

The application is WIP, so I have some time to update the application to the new version (if is recommended) considering the braking changes, is not a big deal, so my question is if recommended to update to the version 2.0.0 preview in this context or is better to wait for a more stable version?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally suggest wait for a more stable version to use. Even the braking changes may not be a big deal for this particulate case but considering there are few known bugs and unknown ones i think the preview version is far from stable.

Although, Docs mentioned you can choice your whatever library your want and you really want to try it now. i strongly suggest test it in the sandbox environment first before you change it on live.

> The Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library does not include any default
>   authentication implementations. Instead, the user will want to
>   authenticate with the library of their choice, or against the OAuth
>   endpoint directly, and built-in DelegateAuthenticationProvider class
>   to authenticate each request. For more information on

Comment: Thanks, that is my concern, about possible new bugs and stability, but I'm testing this new version without issues, for my specific scenario at least.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same question, I decided to build a test project for the 2.0.0-preview of MSAL. The breaking changes around `IUser` -> `IAccount` were straightforward to deal with and the 2.0.0-preview version works fine for my specific use of the `**Public**ClientApplication`.
I recommend to test out your scenarios in a test context before moving it into your project per se.
Feel free to use my test code to get started or just inspired:
[TestOneDrive.zip](http://dev.dbquity.com/stackoverflow/testonedrive.zip)
:-)

Comment: Thanks for the example, so have you decided to use the new version 2.0.0-preview in a production environment?

Comment: Not quite. I am in the initial development phase of a brand new product, so whilst I am using 2.0.0-preview in my main track of work, it is not yet a production environment.